# excel lookup that alters URL for web based data pull

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to figure this out for 5 days, searched this site, watched youtube tutorials, and it's just not coming together for me.  I know very little excel and no visual basic.

I need to be able to pull specific info from a website and populate an excel sheet with that info.

User-entered data (the variable?) is an email address.  I have a long list of email addresses.  From this list I want to generate the web data pull.

My excel is currently set up as a form, Column 1=email, that is the info I have.  What I want to pull is in columns 2-8:  2=id number, 3=first name, 4=last name, etc.

The site I am pulling from is an internal API, looks like:  http://blah.web.blah.com/blah/blah/blah/emailAddress.  This site displays each value that I seek as:

```
<id>12345</id>, <firstName>Joe</firstName>
```

The site has over 25 lines of info tagged like this, I am only interested in pulling 7 specific lines into the appropriate column and row, based on the email value in Column 1.

I can easily capture all 25+ lines of info, one at a time.

```
=HYPERLINK("blah.web.blah.com/blah/blah/blah/"&A3
```

I would prefer to do this as a batch where I paste the email addresses into Column 1 and walk away while the magic computer executes the batch.

...this seems like it should be easy, but I don't know how to do it and haven't found a solution that starts to function.  And like a seasoned Russian once said, "What is hard? Everything you do not know."

Comment: Can you share the code you have used to capture all the lines one at a time? It helps to have a starting point.

Comment: Sure, it's =HYPERLINK("https://blah.web.blah.com/blah/blah/blah/"&A3  A3 is the first email address on the list

Comment: Looks like you should look into looping through the email addresses you have. Start here, and where that leads you. http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VBALoops.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you have excel 2013 , you can use FilterXML function